# Overlay a number of colormaps with matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, imshow

I have a total of 16 color maps which look as follows:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to overlay all the maps while retaining their color? That means, I want to obtain a final image which consists of 16 distributions with different colors. I've been searching a lot, but unfortunately didn't find anything good yet. Thank's a lot!

For reproduction, the code looks as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors


def softmax(logit_map):
    bn, kn, h, w = logit_map.shape
    map_norm = F.softmax(logit_map.reshape(bn, kn, -1), dim=2).reshape(bn, kn, h, w)
    return map_norm

def get_mu_and_prec(part_maps, device, scal):
    """
        Calculate mean for each channel of part_maps
        :param part_maps: tensor of part map activations [bn, n_part, h, w]
        :return: mean calculated on a grid of scale [-1, 1]
        """
    bn, nk, h, w = part_maps.shape
    y_t = torch.linspace(-1., 1., h).reshape(h, 1).repeat(1, w).unsqueeze(-1)
    x_t = torch.linspace(-1., 1., w).reshape(1, w).repeat(h, 1).unsqueeze(-1)
    meshgrid = torch.cat((y_t, x_t), dim=-1).to(device) # 64 x 64 x 2

    mu = torch.einsum('ijl, akij -> akl', meshgrid, part_maps) # bn x nk x 2
    mu_out_prod = torch.einsum('akm,akn->akmn', mu, mu)

    mesh_out_prod = torch.einsum('ijm,ijn->ijmn', meshgrid, meshgrid)
    stddev = torch.einsum('ijmn,akij->akmn', mesh_out_prod, part_maps) - mu_out_prod

    a_sq = stddev[:, :, 0, 0]
    a_b = stddev[:, :, 0, 1]
    b_sq_add_c_sq = stddev[:, :, 1, 1]
    eps = 1e-12

    a = torch.sqrt(a_sq + eps)  # Σ = L L^T Prec = Σ^-1  = L^T^-1 * L^-1  ->looking for L^-1 but first L = [[a, 0], [b, c]
    b = a_b / (a + eps)
    c = torch.sqrt(b_sq_add_c_sq - b ** 2 + eps)
    z = torch.zeros_like(a)

    det = (a * c).unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1)
    row_1 = torch.cat((c.unsqueeze(-1), z.unsqueeze(-1)), dim=-1).unsqueeze(-2)
    row_2 = torch.cat((-b.unsqueeze(-1), a.unsqueeze(-1)), dim=-1).unsqueeze(-2)
    L_inv = scal / (det + eps) * torch.cat((row_1, row_2), dim=-2)  # L^⁻1 = 1/(ac)* [[c, 0], [-b, a]
    return mu, L_inv

def get_heat_map(mu, L_inv, device):
    h, w, nk = 64, 64, L_inv.shape[1]

    y_t = torch.linspace(-1., 1., h).reshape(h, 1).repeat(1, w).unsqueeze(-1)
    x_t = torch.linspace(-1., 1., w).reshape(1, w).repeat(h, 1).unsqueeze(-1)

    y_t_flat = y_t.reshape(1, 1, 1, -1)
    x_t_flat = x_t.reshape(1, 1, 1, -1)

    mesh = torch.cat((y_t_flat, x_t_flat), dim=-2).to(device)
    dist = mesh - mu.unsqueeze(-1)
    proj_precision = torch.einsum('bnik, bnkf -> bnif', L_inv, dist) ** 2  # tf.matmul(precision, dist)**2
    proj_precision = torch.sum(proj_precision, -2)  # sum x and y axis
    heat = 1 / (1 + proj_precision)
    heat = heat.reshape(-1, nk, h, w)  # bn number parts width height

    return heat

color_list = ['black', 'gray', 'brown', 'chocolate', 'orange', 'gold', 'olive', 'lawngreen', 'aquamarine', 
              'dodgerblue', 'midnightblue', 'mediumpurple', 'indigo', 'magenta', 'pink', 'springgreen']

fmap = torch.randn(1, 16, 64, 64)
fmap_norm = softmax(fmap)
mu, L_inv = get_mu_and_prec(fmap_norm, 'cpu', scal=5.)
heat_map = get_heat_map(mu, L_inv, "cpu")

for i in range(16):
    cmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap',
                                           ['white', color_list[i]],
                                           256)
    plt.imshow(heat_map[0][i].numpy(), cmap=cmap)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Overlay in what way? What do you want for the output. If they are all the same shape and have opaque colors, then when overlaying, the last one will be the only one visible. You can stack them side-by-side if you want as an alternate. Or you can write them to a tiff file as multiple pages or to GIF as an animation.

Comment: The dots are supposed to be at different positions (I am training a neural network for that task). The dots should represent landmarks for a person, while the dot in each map represents one landmark. Therefore, the overlayed image should contain all the landmarks, represented by dots in different colors.

Comment: You will need to have the background as transparent to avoid covering a lower image by the white of the next image that is overlaid. But I suspect that some dots will still overlap. The center colors are rather condensed.